# Sum if blank leave it empty

Tags: excel, function, sum, formula

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mlnV.png

This picture shows the column H is subtracting column A,C,E. If you look at row no H:11 it shows 0 because there is not data found. What I want to do is leave it empty when there is no data. And lastly if I add more data to A C E columns the formula automatically populates the number without me scrolling down I am not sure but I think it is sumarray formula.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Oqvf.png (This link shows the image of H column formula)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your info at the simplest level since you fail to show data either input or results, this is a first guess:

=if(and(a1="",d1="",e1=""),"",a1-sum(d1+e1)

So if all cells are blank then blank.